# What is the host in this schematic?

Tags: smbus

In this schematic it shows the smbus as a separate unit, what im wanting to know is this a seperate ic that i have to integrate in or is it just simple as a usb port?
[image]
<sub>(source: [www.ti.com](http://www.ti.com/ods/images/SLUSA78C/sys_sch_A_lusa78.gif))</sub>

Comment: It is something that at very least implementing SMBus, DigIO and ADC interfaces... From the context I can guess it is some kind of microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

This host can be a micro controller or a random i2c (SMBus) master.
I guess this schematic is from the datasheet. The host does the configuration and control.

Answer (score 0):

SMB = System Management Bus, essentially I2C.

SMB (or I2C) are nothing like "USB" in any way.

Most (all?) microcontroller chips support I2C.

- Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus
- Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C